# Setting Java DNS cache TTL

Tags: java, dns

I'm attempting to change the DNS cache timeout in Java 1.6. I see discussion [here](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/java-dns-cache-reference-guide.html) of using something like the following:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty ("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , TTL_SECS);
```

But I've tried this simple test in Win 7....

```
System.out.println("DEFAULT DNS TTL: "+sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get());
java.security.Security.setProperty ("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "123");    
System.out.println("DEFAULT DNS TTL: "+sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get());
```

... and the output doesn't change. It seems this can be changed in the Java installation's security properties but I preffer to keep this in the code for neatness. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: The very link you cited suggests that "setProperty()" ("Option #2") doesn't work.  Q: Did you try "Option#1" (edit jre/lib/security/java.security)?  What did you find?  What Java version are you using?

Comment: True, I seem to have confirmed what a commenter said. Haven't tried option #1 from the link, would much rather this was in code not config. I'm using 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not system properties: they are set in the java.security file. For the corresponding system properties, which are non-preferred, see 'Sun implementation-specific properties' in [Networking Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html).

Comment: Correct.  For a full list of ways to set DNS caching TTL (including as a -D flag or system property), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256556/any-way-to-make-java-honor-the-dns-caching-timeout-ttl.

Answer (score 14):

Try this and see the output you get. The property needs to be set when the class is loaded.

```
static {
    java.security.Security.setProperty ("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "12");    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("DEFAULT DNS TTL: "+sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get());
    java.security.Security.setProperty ("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "123");    
    System.out.println("DEFAULT DNS TTL: "+sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get());
}
```

Comment: Would this be OK for Spring Boot 2 app? I put a println and it seems this is executed 2 times. Would that be a problem?  Also if i try to put it in @ Configuration class it seems println executes after Hikari connects to the DB.
UPDATE:It seems it was executed twice because i used spring-boot-devtools

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and earlier, DNS caching was performed both by InetAddress and by the C library, which meant that DNS TTLs could not be honored correctly. In later releases, caching is done solely by the C library and DNS TTLs are honored.

[Google desc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html)